# can anyone explain the output of the following code in c

Tags: c, recursion

Can anyone explain the output of the following code? I don't understand how the output is what my compiler is showing. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int count)
{

    printf("%d\n", count);

    if(count < 4)
    {
      fun(fun(fun(++count)));
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{

     fun(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you seeing?  what is the output?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what were you expecting?

Comment: the output shown is 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 ... how is 3 coming again after 4 s?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to follow it, you can, but keep track of your call stack carefully.

```
main: fun(1)
main: fun(1):                                               prints 1
main: fun(1): fun(2):                                       prints 2
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3):                               prints 3
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [1st call]:            prints 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [1st call]:  returns 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [2nd call]:            prints 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [2nd call]:  returns 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [3rd call]:            prints 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3): fun(4) [3rd call]:  returns 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(3):                     returns 4
main: fun(1): fun(2): fun(4):                     returns 4
...
```

And so on... it gets a bit tedious.  Perhaps you could simplify by reducing the '< 4' to '< 2' and have just two recursive calls to `fun()`. Then it would be easier to follow.